# Index and Match in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I don't know where I'm missing. I'm trying to provide the formula from a specific row to the last row in an **excel table**. I'm getting "unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class: 1004" error
when I use worksheetfunction.match and "Run time Error - 13 - Type Mismatch" when I use Application.match

Below is the code I have tried:

```
Sub PTO_Calculations()

Dim UBSht As Worksheet
Dim x As Long

'Variables for PTO Data
Dim PTOSht As Worksheet
Dim PTORows As Long, PTOCols As Long
Dim PTOOldRows As Long
Dim PTOWholeRange As Range
Dim PTOFirstColumnRange As Range
Dim PTOFirstRowRange As Range

'Variables for Table in UB Sht
Dim UBTable As ListObject
Dim UBTableRows As Long, UBTableCols As Long
Dim UBTableOldRows As Long

Set UBSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UB - US & IND")
Set PTOSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PTO Data")

Set UBTable = UBSht.ListObjects("UB_US_IND")
UBTableRows = UBTable.ListRows.Count + 1
UBTableCols = UBTable.ListColumns.Count
UBTableOldRows = UBTableRows - WorksheetFunction.CountIf(UBSht.Range("A:A"), Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm - yyyy")) 'UBSht.Range("XFD1").Value

PTORows = PTOSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
PTOCols = PTOSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PTOWholeRange = PTOSht.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(PTORows, PTOCols).Address)
Set PTOFirstColumnRange = PTOSht.Range("A:A")
Set PTOFirstRowRange = PTOSht.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(1, PTOCols).Address)

'I'M FACING ERROR IN THE BELOW STEP
Range(UBTable.Range(UBTableOldRows + 1, 6), UBTable.Range(UBTableRows, 6)).Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(PTOWholeRange, Application.Match([@[Team Member Name]], PTOFirstColumnRange, 0), Application.Match([@Month], PTOFirstRowRange, 0))

end sub
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: First step, use a reference to the actual cells instead of `[@[Team Member Name]]` and `[@Month]`

Comment: it means that the value is not found in the range and it is trying to return an error.   You need to separate the match from the rest and then use a variant to hold the value and test if it is an error or not.

Comment: `UBTable.Range(UBTableOldRows + 1, 6)` also is incorrect. it should be `UBTable.Cells(UBTableOldRows + 1, 6)`

Comment: ^^^ As is `UBTable.Range(UBTableRows, 6)` .

Comment: Also,`PTOSht.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(PTORows, PTOCols).Address)` should be `PTOSht.Range(PTOSht.Cells(1, 1), PTOSht.Cells(PTORows, PTOCols))`  Changing it to an address just so excel can change it back to a number is unnecessary calcs.

Comment: I have tried this and it is throwing "Object Doesn't support Property or Method" error

`Range(UBTable.Cells(UBTableOldRows + 1, 6), UBTable.Cells(UBTableRows, 6)).Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(PTOWholeRange, Application.Match("""& RC[-2]&""", PTOFirstColumnRange, 0), Application.Match("""& RC[-5]&""", PTOFirstRowRange, 0))`

Comment: `UBTable.DataBodyRange.Cells` or `UBTable.Range.Cells` depending on whether you're not including the table header or are including it.

Comment: `"""& RC[-5]&"""`... no, something more like `UBTable.ListObjects("Team Member Name").DataBodyRange.Cells(somecellnumber)`. This really needs broken up into several steps.

Comment: Even more importantly, the result of `Index/Match` is going to be *one* value, not a separate value for each row. I'd say switch to using a `Variant` array and ditch the Index/Match approach.

Comment: I have even tried loop as below: I'm still getting Type Mismatch

`For x = UBTableOldRows + 1 To UBTableRows
  UBTable.Range(x, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(PTOWholeRange, Application.Match(UBTable.ListColumns("Team Member Name").DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 4), PTOFirstColumnRange, 0), Application.Match(UBTable.ListColumns("Month").DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 1), PTOFirstRowRange, 0))
Next x`

Comment: That means the `Match` didn't find a match. You need to use `IsError` to test ... as mentioned this needs broken up into several lines. Save the result of the `Application.Match` in a variable, test if it's an error. If not, use that variable within `Index`.